# Apache poi getCell() returns wrong value

Tags: java, apache-poi

So im trying to recive cell value like '150symbols150symbols150symbols150symbols150symbols150symbols150symbols150symbols150symbols150symbols150symbols150symbols150symbols150symbols150symbol'

In some cases ill get correct (150...) value and in some reciving '78.0'. At first i thouth that i got wrong cell type in my .xls but after some work i found that they are the same. Also calling method getCellType returns me '1' and that is CELL_TYPE_STRING.

In the end its working something like this:

```
String value1 = getCellValue(row.getCell(0)); --150... correct value
String value2 = getCellValue(row.getCell(1)); --150... correct value
String value3 = getCellValue(row.getCell(2)); --78.0   incorrect value
 
private String getCellValue(Cell cell) {
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: //similar for other cell types
            //getting cell value based on its type
    }
}
```

looking for some advices and tips cause im running out of ideas, maby im missing something?

thats how my excel looks :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWU0f.png)

p.s. there are many '150...' vals just for testing

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getCell(int var1)` to get the content in a cell. But it returns the object of [Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) class. You should use methods in `Cell` class to get values in Excel cells. There are methods like

- `getDateCellValue()`
- `getNumericCellValue()`
- `getStringCellValue()`

to get the cell content depending on the [CellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html). Using CellType, you can decide how to get the cell content.

**UPDATE:**

If the problem still exists, check the data type of the cell from;[image]

And do the necessary changes in the code to get the correct value.

**Small tip:** Also you can add a single quote `'` at the beginning of the cell content. Then Apache POI will get the cell content as a String. The `'` will not become a part of the cell content.

Comment: probably, i needed to add more of my code. Im already using all thoose methods, but still no result.

Comment: If only that particular cell gives the issue, then issue might be with the content. To check that try replacing the cell content with a simple String and check the return value. If it works, then shorten the String and check the return value. (Eg:- First try with first 10 '150symbols' String. If it works, then try with first 20 '150symbols' String. Expand the String in that pattern and check the return value.) Then you will be able to identify the reason.